# LinqToExcel Is it possible to read the formula as a string

Tags: c#, excel, linq, linq-to-excel

I've encountered a problem. I'm trying to read data from xlsx document using LinqToExcel. The data is retrieved but the document has cells which are interpreted as formulas with text like "=- Something". Is it possible to get those cells text and not the counted value of the formula?

```
var book = new LinqToExcel.ExcelQueryFactory(path);
var worksheetNames = book.GetWorksheetNames();

var query =           
    from row in book.WorksheetNoHeader()
    where row[0] != ""
    select row;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With **LinqToExcel** you can't receive formula, because `linqtoExcel` uses **OleDB** to access sheet. **OleDB** **doesn't allow to access formulas**. Instead `linqtoExcel` you can use [Worksheet.Range Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.worksheet.range.aspx)

**Example:**

```
Range range = (Range)sheet.Cells[i, j];
return range.Formula;
```